# How to redeem a discord nitro code with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Guys i want to know how to redeem a discord nitro code with **https://discord.js.org/#/** library 
which function should i use to make this work ?!

Answer (score 4):

Bots in discord cannot have nitro.